# rest-open-uri on heroku with ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-2.0

Since the default encoding is now utf-8 for Ruby 2.0, the rest-open-uri gem throws the following error on heroku:

> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require': /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rest-open-uri-1.0.0/lib/rest-open-uri.rb:413: invalid multibyte escape: /[\r\n\t !#-[]-~\x80-\xff]+|(\[\x00-\x7f])/ (SyntaxError)

I need to change the following line in rest-open-uri.rb. How can I access this file on heroku?

lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rest-open-uri-1.0.0/lib/rest-open-uri.rb

```
# encoding: US-ASCII
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rest-open-uri` looks like a dead project.  Do you want to get in the business of patching up 8 year old code to get your application to work?

It looks like [rf-rest-open-uri](https://github.com/rfletcher/rest-open-uri) is a more up-to-date fork of that project, have you tried it?  I don't see any `encoding` instruction in that gem's `rest-open-uri.rb` source file.